Laravel Queue Work Freezes on Database Insert in Production but Works Fine Locally
I’m experiencing an issue with a queue worker in my Laravel application. Here’s the situation:

Every 10 minutes, a job fetches 10 new data items from mqtt and insert them to redis queue and a queue work process them into the database.
The first batch of 10 items inserts successfully.
After 10 minutes, when the second batch of 10 items arrives, the process logs that it started but freezes when trying to insert into the database.

This problem only occurs in my production environment. However, when I use the same production database in my local environment, everything works fine.

Checked Laravel logs for errors but found no relevant issues.
Verified database logs and found no deadlocks or slow queries.
Ensured that there are no duplicate job dispatches or overlapping transactions.
Monitored server resources like CPU, memory, and database connections, and everything seems fine.


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

you can disable the queue worker and run it manually. with enough "echo()" and "microtime()" you can debug your issue even further and pinpoint the cause.

I have workers in laravel with kubernetes, you check if close al transactions  or if you clean any static variable after finish the job?

are transactions enabled on prod and not on dev?  Can you post your .env files (remove codes)

What do you do after a record is inserted into the database? Sometimes an after-insert process works fine on the local environment because of the small amount of data and dedicated machine ... but the same process takes too much time on production as the amount of data is more and server resources also are not dedicated to your website. So this can be a place where you can investigate further.
